# sampling using L1 optimization

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, signal-processing, sampling, sampling-theory

[image]

[image]

As much as I understand the F should be the interval medians (correct me if I wrong), according to the next slide, where is also the Loss function defined:

[image]

[image]

What I don't understand is the next note in the question:

[image]

What does this assumption gives me ?
Why do I need it ?
What information does it gives me that the integral over the reciprocal of $f$ is 0 ?
How does this assumption expressed in the proof of the MAD or in it's loss?
Thank you in advance.